# Calculating sums in tree structures using caching

Tags: algorithm, caching, recursion, data-structures, tree

i need to know what type of algorithm calculates sums in tree structures efficiently with the help of caching mechanism.

The problem i want to solve is easy: there are two types of nodes: Folders (F) and Files (L) ... looks like a file system :) ...

Folders and Files can be created and moved within the tree structure. Files have changing sizes.

Now i want a function `size(node)` that returns the node's content size.

Sample:

```
F1
 - L1 : 10
 - L2 : 33
F2 
 - F21
    - F211
         - L3 : 2
         - L4 : 8
    - F212
         - F2121
               - L5 : 18
         - F2122
               - L6 : 21
               - L7 : 3            

size(node) gives:

size(F1):43
size(F2):52
size(F21):52
size(F211):10
size(F212):42
size(L5):18
...
```

Known solution is to add up recursively :) ...

```
size(node) 
  int res=0;
  if(node is File)
    return sizeOfFile(node)
  else
    for each child of node
      res += size(child)
    end 
  end
  return res
end
```

**I ask myself wether i can make use of some type of caching here. What is the name and type of algorithms i need to search for?**

Comment: the obvious solution is to add the *size* to the  `F`-nodes and propagate the changes upwards if a size is changed - I don't think there is a name for that

Comment: If you decide to cache a value, make sure to invalidate it if you change something in the subtree below. I.e. if you move a subtree from directory A to directory B, you will have to invalidate (and recompute) every cached directory size on the paths from A and B to the root of the filesystem. 

FWIW, there are data structures to maintain aggregations like yours on a dynamic tree in logarithmic time per operation (e.g. link/cut trees), but that seems overkill if your nesting depth is usually "small". Also the constant factors for these dynamic trees are unpractically large usually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one thing you can do. You can compute the cost when you visit a node and store it. Think this like the storage on your phone or pc. An example would be better here.[image]

I haven't given the cost to any node here. Lets say you visit the node number 4. you compute the cost by adding cost of 6 and 7 and store it on a database. On a Database this could be stored like `directory path -- cost` . Now lets say you want to compute the cost of 2. You don't need to visit 4 as you've already precomputed the cost. You only need to compute the cost of 5 and then you are done. Thus we store the cost of 5 and 2 on the Database. Next time if you want to know the size of 4 or 5, you can just fetch that from the DB.

I'm assuming this is a file structure. So you will need to go to directories more often. The more you visit the more storing of sizes will be done. The more easier it will get to compute the cost. In the end if you change the files or move them, just compute the cost of that node only.

I think the advantage here will be that you wont need to compute cost every time you visit a node. you will be using a storage that will make your computation of size much much faster as time goes by.

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thank you. This looks good and quite similar to the proposal from @Carsten. Thus, i've learned: 1.) each node needs a parent link and an additional size property (serves for size caching) 2.) when a node's size is changing (either by moving a node or by changing the file's size), i need to propagate the size changes upwards (that looks as easy calculation in the case of file size changes, bit more tricky in the case of moving a node).

Comment: @MarkusSchmid Think of a move of X bytes as adding +X bytes in one place while adding -X bytes in another

Answer (score 0):

Attached an implementation using swift and core data. What it does is generating random tree data in a core data / sqlite database and moving some nodes (folders) into other target folders. Output looks like that:

```
Building the tree ...
insert file nodes: [0(15): 1  100]
insert file nodes: [1(15): 101  200]
insert file nodes: [2(15): 201  300]
insert file nodes: [3(15): 301  400]
insert file nodes: [4(15): 401  500]
insert file nodes: [5(15): 501  600]
insert file nodes: [6(15): 601  700]
insert file nodes: [7(15): 701  800]
insert file nodes: [8(15): 801  900]
insert file nodes: [9(15): 901  1000]
insert file nodes: [10(15): 1001  1100]
insert file nodes: [11(15): 1101  1200]
insert file nodes: [12(15): 1201  1300]
insert file nodes: [13(15): 1301  1400]
insert file nodes: [14(15): 1401  1500]
Congratulations! Tree exists. It's initial size is:75563
Moving F000120 to target folder F000103 ...
before moving:
size[F000120] = 607 path = /F000001/F000003/
source folder: size[F000003] = 37388
target folder: size[F000103] = 1134
after moving:
size[F000120] = 607 path = /F000001/F000003/F000014/F000030/F000072/F000103/
source folder: size[F000003] = 37995
target folder: size[F000103] = 1741
Moving F000200 to target folder F000209 ...
before moving:
size[F000200] = 224 path = /F000001/F000016/
source folder: size[F000016] = 1686
target folder: size[F000209] = 215
after moving:
size[F000200] = 224 path = /F000001/F000002/F000006/F000007/F000041/F000209/
source folder: size[F000016] = 1462
target folder: size[F000209] = 439
Moving the nodes completed. Tree size is:75563
```

Core data model is:

[image]

`AppDelegate`:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  SizesNTrees
//
//  Created by Markus Schmid on 20.02.16.
//

import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    // MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
        let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
        return urls[urls.count-1]
    }()

    lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
        let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("SizesNTrees", withExtension: "momd")!
        return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
    }()

    lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
        let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
        let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("SizesNTrees.sqlite")
        var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
        do {
            try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
        } catch {
            var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
            dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
            dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

            dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
            let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }

        return coordinator
    }()

    lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        return managedObjectContext
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
            do {
                try managedObjectContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

`ViewController`:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  SizesNTrees
//
//  Created by Markus Schmid on 20.02.16.
//

import UIKit
import CoreData

enum NodeType: Int {
    case File
    case Folder
}

var node : Node!

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let root=nodeWithName("F000001") {
            print("Tree exists. Initial tree size is:\(root.size!)")
        }
        else {
            print("Building the tree ...")
            buildTree(300, noFiles:1500)
        }
        if let root=nodeWithName("F000001") {
            print("Congratulations! Tree exists. It's initial size is:\(root.size!)")
            moveNode("F000120",targetFolderName:"F000103")
            moveNode("F000200",targetFolderName:"F000209")
            print("Moving the nodes completed. Tree size is:\(root.size!)")
        }
        else {
            print("Tree is missing.")
            return
        }
        do {
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
            try managedContext.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func moveNode(nodeName:String, targetFolderName:String) {
        // try to move move nodeName to targetFolderName
        if let node=nodeWithName(nodeName) {
            if let targetFolder=nodeWithName(targetFolderName) {
                print ("Moving \(nodeName) to target folder \(targetFolderName) ... ")
                print("before moving:")
                print("   size[\(node.name!)] = \(node.size!) path = \(path(node))")
                let origParent=node.parent
                print("   source folder: size[\(origParent!.name!)] = \(origParent!.size!)")
                print("   target folder: size[\(targetFolder.name!)] = \(targetFolder.size!)")
                if !isDescendantOrSelf(targetFolder, ascendant: node) {
                    move(node, toFolder: targetFolder)
                    print("after moving:")
                    print("   size[\(node.name!)] = \(node.size!) path = \(path(node))")
                    print("   source folder: size[\(origParent!.name!)] = \(origParent!.size!)")
                    print("   target folder: size[\(targetFolder.name!)] = \(targetFolder.size!)")
                }
                else {
                    print ("Moving folder to target folder failed! Target folder is descendant from folder.")
                }
            }
            else {
                print ("Target folder \(targetFolderName) not found!")
            }
        }
        else {
            print ("Node \(nodeName) not found!")
        }
    }

    func buildTree(noFolders:Int,noFiles:Int) {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
        let nodeEntity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Node", inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)
        // create folders
        autoreleasepool {
            for index in 1...noFolders {
                node = NSManagedObject(entity: nodeEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext) as! Node
                node.name=String(format: "F%06d", index)
                node.size=0
                node.type=NodeType.Folder.rawValue
                node.nr=index
                if index>1 {
                    node.parent=nodeOfType(NodeType.Folder.rawValue, nr:Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(index-1))+1))
                }
            }
            do {
                try managedContext.save()
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
            managedContext.reset()
        }
        // create files
        let bSize = 100
        let noB = noFiles/bSize
        var index = 0
        for var bNr=0;(bNr<noB || ((bNr*bSize<noFiles) && (((bNr+1)*bSize)>noFiles)) );bNr++ {
            autoreleasepool {
                var startIndex=0
                var maxIndex=0
                if bNr<noB {
                    startIndex=bNr*bSize+1
                    maxIndex=(bNr+1)*bSize
                }
                else {
                    startIndex=bNr*bSize+1
                    maxIndex=noFiles
                }
                print("insert file nodes: [\(bNr)(\(noB)): \(startIndex)  \(maxIndex)]")
                for index=startIndex;index<maxIndex+1;index++ {
                    let node = NSManagedObject(entity: nodeEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext) as! Node
                    node.name=String(format: "L%06d", index)
                    node.size=Int(arc4random_uniform(100)+1)
                    node.type=NodeType.File.rawValue
                    node.nr=index
                    node.parent=self.nodeOfType(NodeType.Folder.rawValue, nr:Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(noFolders))+1))
                }
                do {
                    try managedContext.save()
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                }
                managedContext.reset()
            }
        }

        fillSize();
    }

    func nodeWithName(name:String, context:NSManagedObjectContext) -> Node? {
        var node : Node?
        let managedContext = context
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"name = %@", name)
        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Node")
        request.predicate=predicate

        do {
            let fetchedNodes = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [Node]
            if fetchedNodes.count>0 {
                node=fetchedNodes[0]
            }
            else {
                node=nil
            }
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to fetch nodes: \(error)")
        }
        return node
    }

    func nodeOfType(type:NSNumber, nr:NSNumber, context:NSManagedObjectContext) -> Node? {
        var node : Node?
        let managedContext = context
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"type = %@ AND nr = %@", type, nr)
        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Node")
        request.predicate=predicate

        do {
            let fetchedNodes = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [Node]
            if fetchedNodes.count>0 {
                node=fetchedNodes[0]
            }
            else {
                node=nil
            }
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to fetch nodes: \(error)")
        }
        return node
    }

    func nodeWithName(name:String) -> Node? {
        var node : Node?
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"name = %@", name)
        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Node")
        request.predicate=predicate

        do {
            let fetchedNodes = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [Node]
            if fetchedNodes.count>0 {
                node=fetchedNodes[0]
            }
            else {
                node=nil
            }
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to fetch nodes: \(error)")
        }
        return node
    }


    func nodeOfType(type:NSNumber, nr:NSNumber) -> Node? {
        var node : Node?
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"type = %@ AND nr = %@", type, nr)
        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Node")
        request.predicate=predicate

        do {
            let fetchedNodes = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [Node]
            if fetchedNodes.count>0 {
                node=fetchedNodes[0]
            }
            else {
                node=nil
            }
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to fetch nodes: \(error)")
        }
        return node
    }

    func fillSize() {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"type = 1")
        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Node")
        request.predicate=predicate
        do {
            let fetchedNodes = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [Node]
            for node in fetchedNodes {
                node.size=size(node);
            }
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to fetch nodes: \(error)")
        }
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }

    func size(node:Node) -> Int {
        var res : Int = 0
        if node.type == 0 {
            res=(node.size?.integerValue)!;
        }
        else {
            if let nodeChilds=node.childs {
                for child in nodeChilds {
                    res = res + size(child);
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    func path(node:Node) -> String {
        if let parent=node.parent {
            return path(parent).stringByAppendingString((node.parent?.name)!).stringByAppendingString("/")
        }
        else {
            return "/"
        }
    }

    func move(node:Node, toFolder:Node) -> Bool {
        var success=false
        if let size=node.size {
            if let parent=node.parent {
                if parent.isEqual(toFolder) {
                    return true
                }
                else {
                    propagateSizeChange(-size.integerValue, parent: parent)
                }
            }
            propagateSizeChange(size.integerValue, parent: toFolder)
            node.parent=toFolder
            success=true
        }
        return success
    }

    func setSizeFor(file:Node, var newSize:Int) {
        if newSize<=0 {
            newSize=0
        }
        if let size=node.size {
            if let parent=node.parent {
                propagateSizeChange(newSize-size.integerValue, parent: parent)
            }
        }
    }

    func isDescendantOrSelf(node:Node, ascendant:Node) -> Bool {
        var success=false
        if ascendant.isEqual(node) {
            return true
        }
        else {
            if let nodeChilds=ascendant.childs {
                if nodeChilds.contains(node) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    for child in nodeChilds {
                        success = (success || self.isDescendantOrSelf(node,ascendant:child))
                        if success {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return success
    }

    func propagateSizeChange(value:Int, parent:Node) {
        if parent.type == 1 {
            parent.size = NSNumber(integer:(parent.size!.integerValue + value))
            if let parent=parent.parent {
                parent.size = NSNumber(integer:(parent.size!.integerValue + value))
                propagateSizeChange(value, parent: parent)
            }
        }
    }
}
```